# Concat Template With Custom Directive Template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm not sure if its possible to achieve what I want. I'll try to explain it with an example:

a custom directive:

```
appDirectives.directive("myTestDirective",
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "<div> Some template here... {{ testObject }} <div>",
            scope: {
                 'testObject' = '@testObject'
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Use directive in a tempalte:

```
<my-test-directive testObject="And some more here...">
    <div>
         I also want to be in the template!
    </di>
</my-test-directive>
```

And I want to achieve this template:

```
<div> Some template here... And some more here... <div>
<div>
    I also want to be in the template!
</di>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude). Just add a param to the directive, and use `ng-transclude` on the element you want to have the contents be inserted.

You might have to remove some the original since the transclusion needs an element to operate on, but this is the basic idea.

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .directive('myTestDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      template: "<div> Some template here... {{testObject}} <div><div ng-transclude></div>",
      scope: {
        testObject: '@'
      },
      transclude: true
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <my-test-directive test-object="And some more here...">
    <div>
      I also want to be in the template!
    </div>
  </my-test-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thank you. I was aware of transclude but it seems that I didn't know where to place ng-transclude :)